# Medusa returns Segmentation fault or gives up on 1st try

Tags: linux, security, php, http, kali-linux

For my thesis, which is about the use of software for computer forensics, I want to use Medusa to attack a server of my own, just to sniff the packets to see the data for port 80 (and therefore prove that an attack occurs).

The module used is web-form, because as you can see [here](http://83.212.100.186), I made a form to use if for the attack, cuz the http module only works for other kind of login.

But when I'm executing this command:

```
medusa -h 83.212.100.186 -u xampp -P *.txt -M web-form
```

it says **Segmentation fault**

I have no idea why it happens. Testing it at other hosts, works ok.

Also, I tested some other commands, like with only one password file used or with a specific password or with different username, to find out what's going on and some of them which didn't return the fault, returned **HTTP 301** or **302**. Therefore, the only thing I figured is that web-form doesn't work when redirect occurs.

I wrote the PHP code of that form and here's what it does when it checks the credentials:

```
if($user && $word)

{echo "Success";}

else

{echo "<form id='form1' method='post' action='index.php'>
<b>Username:</b><br />
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' /><br /><br />
<b>Password:</b><br />
<input type='password' name='password' id='password'></input><br /><br />
<input type='submit' value='Send' />
</form>";}
```

I posted the PHP, in case there's anything to change so to make it work. When it's False, I wrote again the form so to not do any kind of refresh at the page.

**Any idea on what could the Segmentation fault be and how to make Medusa actual attack the host without returning the fault or end with the first try** (with password **aaa**, which is incorrect). The username **xampp** is in database.

Comment: https://github.com/jmk-foofus/medusa/issues/14 issue open in 2016, still not resolved (in 2019)